# CSS Navigation current page

Tags: html, css, menu, state

I have problem with setting up a navigation bar which would show change depending on section I am on page. Hover works fine but not it just stays in regular style when i'm on different pages but it should be in hover state.

This is how my navigation looks like in **HTML**

> ```
>     <nav id="primary">
>             <ul> 
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="home" href="#home">MAIN_PAGE</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="challenge" href="#challenge">CHALLENGE</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="zones" href="#zones">FIVE_LETHAL_ZONES</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="sprintframe" href="#sprintframe">SPRINTFRAME</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="hybridtouch" href="#hybridtouch">HYBRIDTOUCH</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="micoach" href="#micoach">MICOACH_SPEED_CELL</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="traxion" href="#traxion">TRAXION_2.0_FG</a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li>
>                     <a class="shop" href="#shop">SHOP_NOW</a>
>                 </li>
>             </ul>
>         </nav>
> ```

This is how my **CSS** navigation styling looks like(the png is 2 dots in 2 colors.)

```
nav#primary {
    z-index: 100000000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
nav#primary li {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
}
nav#primary a {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: transparent url('../images/nav-dot.png') 4px 4px no-repeat;
}

nav#primary a:hover, nav#primary a.active {
    background: transparent url('../img/nav-dot.png') 4px -16px no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way it's help you:**

```
<div class="menuBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="two.php">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this js

```
$('.menuBar a').click(function(){
    $('.menuBar a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

You can add this code to `end of your html file`(before `</body>`)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    $('.menuBar a').click(function(){
         $('.menuBar a').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with javascripting. What do I have to do in order for it to work on my particular code?

Comment: please review my answer

Comment: Great, it worked BUT it works only when I click on buttons, it's not changing by itself when i scroll down with mouse wheel. Is there a option to add for that?